# Issues using python's string formatting libraries

Tags: python, string, formatting

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO company VALUES (%(cname), %(symbol), %(start_date), %(end_date))' %{'cname' : company, 'symbol' : company, 'start_date' : startdate, 'end_date' : enddate})
```

Trying to run this line on my computer results in a string formatting error:
    ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 36

It seems to be concerning the `,` but I have checked and all the parenthesis are properly nested (none enclosing an errant `,`)

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @imm said.  Also, you may want to use the built in query formatting that is part of MySQLdb.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO company VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (company, company, startdate, enddate))
```

Comment: This response is valid but also you may want to map columns as @imm sais in his response, using dicts. Very confortable way to do it

Answer (score 17):

You need an "s" after each of those positional arguments.

```
(%(cname)s, %(symbol)s,  ....
```

Comment: You saved me hours of debugging. God bless you, sir. This also applies to Postgres using psycopg2 :)